# How to pick last inserted DateTime from each month?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table PriceDate with two columns PriceId and PriceDate with 3-4 entries per month.
I want to retrieve last inserted PriceDate for each month.

This is my table

```
PriceDate                PriceId 
2012-01-07 00:00:00.000  1
2012-01-14 00:00:00.000  2
2012-01-21 00:00:00.000  3
2012-01-28 00:00:00.000  4

2012-02-04 00:00:00.000  5
2012-02-11 00:00:00.000  6
2012-02-18 00:00:00.000  7
2012-02-25 00:00:00.000  8
```

I need this output

```
PriceDate                  DateFormat            PriceId 
2012-01-28 00:00:00.000    Jan 2012              4
2012-02-25 00:00:00.000    Feb 2012              8
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

```
declare @t table (PriceDate datetime not null, PriceId int not null)
insert into @t(PriceDate,PriceId) values
('2012-01-07T00:00:00.000',1),
('2012-01-14T00:00:00.000',2),
('2012-01-21T00:00:00.000',3),
('2012-01-28T00:00:00.000',4),
('2012-02-04T00:00:00.000',5),
('2012-02-11T00:00:00.000',6),
('2012-02-18T00:00:00.000',7),
('2012-02-25T00:00:00.000',8)

;With Numbered as (
    select *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,PriceDate),0)
                ORDER BY PriceDate desc) as rn
    from @t
)
select PriceDate,
       RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(20),PriceDate,106),8) [Dateformat],
       PriceId
from Numbered where rn=1
```

The `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` trick is to basically round every date to the start of its respective month.

Result:

```
PriceDate               Dateformat PriceId
----------------------- --------   -----------
2012-01-28 00:00:00.000 Jan 2012   4
2012-02-25 00:00:00.000 Feb 2012   8
```

Comment: +1 a quick remark - you don't need to dateadd after datediff since it is just for partitioning

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - true, but once I start typing `DATE` the rest of the pattern just flows out without me even thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Damian_The_Unbeliever's but using the `YEAR()` and `Month()` functions

```
;WITH DateOrdered
AS
(
    SELECT PriceDate, PriceId, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY YEAR(PriceDate), MONTH(PriceDate) 
           ORDER BY PriceDate DESC) As Num
            from PriceDate
        )
        SELECT PriceDate, RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(20),PriceDate,106),8) [Dateformat], PriceId
        FROM DateOrdered
        WHERE Num = 1
```